# Hide a button based on a condition in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, button

I have a created custom button in the Case object. The content source is Visualforce Page. If I click that button once, that should be hidden. I referred to some links and they do disable the command button from the onClick action. I don't have that option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Quick Action, you can use [Dynamic Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm&type=5&release=228) to conditionally render the button.

If you're using a normal button, you can't disable the button, but you could have your Apex code not perform the update and/or show an error in Visualforce if the feature cannot be used.